# Jira JQL to filter Kanban board for all issues within "my" epics

Tags: jira, jql

I have a Kanban board with epics assigned to different users. I have the swim lanes configured to group issues by epics.

Now I'd like to have a filter which shows only issues with an epic link where the epic is assigned to me. In other words, I'd like to see "my" epics and everything inside as swim lanes.

Comment: I think you can use "assignee = currentUser()"

Comment: I rather need something like currentIssue.epicLink. assignee == currentUser()

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need [Scriptrunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin for this. you have to do is something like this.

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("issuetype = epic and assignee = currentUser()")
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this imply that the answer to my question is "You cannot do this in Jira JQL"?

Comment: I meant: Does this mean there is no other way besides using a 3rd party plugin?

Comment: as far as I know there are no ways to do this in pure JQL.this plugin supports for advance JQL filtering.